# Access Report from Query inexplicably multiplies columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, ms-access-reports

I have a weird problem. First off, I'm not well versed in Access, but I'm using it for a project to track visibility of log sources and detections and map them to the MITRE ATT&CK Framework. I tables such as Techniques to track the MITRE Techniques, Data_Sources to track the various sources used by those Techniques, and Data_Sources_Coverage that has a visibility ranking for each data source for the company. I have a query built with the below SQL (probably a little messy):

```
SELECT Technique.Name, Technique.ID, Technique.[Tactic ID], Count(Technique.[Data Sources].Value) AS Technique_Sources, Count(Data_Source_Coverage.[Data Source]) AS Sources_Visible
FROM (Data_Sources INNER JOIN Technique ON Data_Sources.Name = Technique.[Data Sources].Value) INNER JOIN Data_Source_Coverage ON Data_Sources.Name = Data_Source_Coverage.[Data Source]
WHERE (Data_Source_Coverage.Coverage)>0)
GROUP BY Technique.Name, Technique.ID, Technique.[Tactic ID];
```

The query works great, prints the results as I expect them. However, when I generate a report from that query things go off the rails. The report inexplicably (I did nothing to the data), multiplies the Technique_Sources column by the Sources_Visible column and displays that in the Technique_Sources Column, and then every entry in the Sources_Visible column becomes a '1'. Pics below. Thanks for the help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a copy of the file? Without seeing how is the report created, it's hard to say what could be happening

Comment: Is [Data Sources} a multi-value field? I never use them. Issue could be related to that.